# How do I integrate graphs in response to query in IBM Watson Conversation chatbot?

Tags: analytics, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-discovery

So when a user type query like 'Which are the top 3 courses where the cut-off percentage is highest in last three years?' The bot should be able to return the data in graphical form (provided I have the datasets available to form the graphs).

Comment: This sounds more like a "Watson Analytics" solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Watson Conversation only for understanding the query of the user, and let an application do heavy lifting of building response.

So, first you will need to configure a dialog node in Watson Conversation to identify the user intent and retrieve the parameters (like "top 3 courser", "last 3 years" for example).

Then you put this information into the `output` object in your response JSON.
(for example `{ output: { action: 'computeCutOffPercentage', coursesCount: '3', period: '3years' }, ..... }`)

Then you define the logic of building response within your application.

More details about this approach can be found in the docs: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/develop-app.html#implementing-app-actions

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna go for what [SimonO'Doherty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1167890/simon-odoherty) mentioned, then you can think of using the Conversation service's response to do the needful for you. Currently, Conversation service is not capable of returning a graph or anything like that. Right now it's simple text only, but you can return a JSON response from it depending on which you can form the graph in your application itself and then show it back to the user. Use the JSON response from Conversation as a trigger, that will activate the graph loading process back in your application.